# Aggregate a data frame based on unordered pairs of columns

Tags: r, aggregate, plyr

I have a data set that looks something like this:

```
     id1  id2   size
1   5400 5505      7
2   5033 5458      1
3   5452 2873     24
4   5452 5213      2
5   5452 4242     26
6   4823 4823      4
7   5505 5400     11
```

Where `id1` and `id2` are unique nodes in a graph, and `size` is a value assigned to the **directed** edge connecting them *from* `id1` *to* `id2`. This data set is fairly large (a little over 2 million rows). What I would like to do is sum the size column, grouped by **unordered node pairs** of `id1` and `id2`. For example, in the first row, we have `id1=5400` and `id2=5505`. There exists another row in the data frame where `id1=5505` and `id2=5400`. In the grouped data, the sum of the size columns for these two rows would be added to a single row. So in other words I want to summarize the data where I'm grouping on an (unordered) set of (id1,id2). I've found a way to do this using `apply` with a custom function that checks for the reversed column pair in the full data set, but this works excruciatingly slow. Does anyone know of a way to do this another way, perhaps with `plyr` or with something in the base packages that would be more efficient?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way is to create extra columns with `pmax` and `pmin` of `id1` and `id2`as follows. I'll use `data.table` solution here.

```
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(DF)
# Following mnel's suggestion, g1, g2 could be used directly in by
# and it could be even shortened by using `id1` and id2` as their names
DT.OUT <- DT[, list(size=sum(size)), 
        by=list(id1 = pmin(id1, id2), id2 = pmax(id1, id2))]
#     id1  id2 size
# 1: 5400 5505   18
# 2: 5033 5458    1
# 3: 5452 2873   24
# 4: 5452 5213    2
# 5: 5452 4242   26
# 6: 4823 4823    4
```

Comment: I think writing it on several lines instead compositions would help th OP + though, you type faster than me

Comment: You could create g1 and g2 in the by argument.

Comment: @mnel, that's brilliant. Will make the edit. Any idea how to remove duplicate rows based on 2 columns without a temp variable?

Comment: Thanks @Arun. The data transformation with a maximum and minimum column appears to do the trick. I'm guessing that if there is any package out there that does this, it uses a similar concept of a pairwise ordering.

Comment: @R_User, not that I'm aware of.

Comment: Why not just `DT[, list(size = sum(size)), by = list(id1 = pmin(id1,id2), id2 = pmax(id1,id2))]` -- that takes care of the duplicates, as it doesn't create them.

Answer (score 8):

an alternate method:

```
R> library(igraph)
R> DF
   id1  id2 size
1 5400 5505    7
2 5033 5458    1
3 5452 2873   24
4 5452 5213    2
5 5452 4242   26
6 4823 4823    4
7 5505 5400   11
R> g  <- graph.data.frame(DF, directed=F)
R> g  <- simplify(g, edge.attr.comb="sum", remove.loops=FALSE)
R> DF <- get.data.frame(g)
R> DF
   id1  id2 size
1 5400 5505   18
2 5033 5458    1
3 5452 2873   24
4 5452 5213    2
5 5452 4242   26
6 4823 4823    4
```

Comment: This solution is much more elegant.