# Combining rows with swapped column values in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with the following feature:

```
one = c("A", "A", "B" ,"C" )
two = c("B", "C", "A", "A")
three = c(150, 0, 0, 160)
four = c(0, 200, 190, 0)

df <- data.frame(one, two, three, four)
df
  one two three four
1   A   B   150    0
2   A   C     0  200
3   B   A     0  190
4   C   A   160    0
```

I would like to combine the rows where the value of column one appears in column two and vice versa to:

```
  one two three four
1   A   B   150  200
2   A   C   190  160
```

Is there a way to do this in dplyr?
Other suggestions are also greatly appreciated.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/15487151

Answer (score 1):

With data.table, you can do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[one > two, c("one","two") := .(two, one)]
df[, lapply(.SD,sum), by=.(one,two)]
```

or with dplyr, the baroque analogue:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(
    bad = one > two, 
    one = ifelse(bad, two, one), 
    two = ifelse(bad, .$one, two), 
    bad = NULL) %>% 
  group_by(one,two) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(sum))
```

The idea is to sort the first and second columns by swapping them where unordered. Taking `pmin` and `pmax` would be another way of sorting, covered in the linked question.