# Sum and order columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a large dataset I want to simplify but I'm currently having some troubles with one thing.
The following table shows a origin destination combination. The count column, represents the amount of occurrences of A to B for example.

```
From    To  count
A       B     2
A       C     1
C       A     3
B       C     1
```

The problem I have is that for example A to C (1), is actually the same as C to A (3). As direction doesn't really matter to me only that there's a connection between A and C, I wonder how can I simply have A to C (4).

The problem is that I have a factor with 400 levels, so I can't do it manually. Is there something with dplyr or similar that can solve this for me?

Comment: You might find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487151/aggregate-a-data-frame-based-on-unordered-pairs-of-columns) helpful

Comment: @alexis_laz Thank you :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df[1:2] <- t(apply(df[1:2], 1, sort))

aggregate(count ~ From + To, df, sum)
```

results in:

```
  From To count
1    A  B     2
2    A  C     4
3    B  C     1
```

Comment: Thank you. It works perfect and it's actually quite simple.
May I ask why the "t(apply(". I understand that it sorts the columns but I'm not really sure why not going directly for the aggregate.

Comment: @FilipeTeixeira you need to operate (the sorting) on the rows, that is why you need `apply(df[1:2], 1, sort)`; in the resulting matrix the original columns are now rows, so you need to transpose them back with the `t`-function

Comment: I get it now. Thank you :).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R method using `aggregate`, `sort`, `paste`, and `mapply`.

```
with(df, aggregate(count,
                   list(route=mapply(function(x, y) paste(sort(c(x, y)), collapse=" - "),
                                                          From, To)), sum))
  route x
1 A - B 2
2 A - C 4
3 B - C 1
```

Here, `mapply` takes pairs of elements from the from and to variables, sorts them and pastes them into a single string with collapse=TRUE. The resulting string vector is used in `aggregate` to group the observations and sum the count values. `with` reduces typing.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Is there any practical difference from the solutions above? It's still interesting to see a different approach, so it's not wasted at all.