# Aggregate a data frame based on unordered three columns

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, data.table

I would like to do the exact same thing as posted here: [Aggregate a data frame based on unordered pairs of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487151/aggregate-a-data-frame-based-on-unordered-pairs-of-columns) But with 3 columns instead of two.

```
   X1   X2    X3   count
   A    B     C      1
   B    A     C      1
   D    N     A      1
   A    D     N      1
   C    B     A      1
   N    D     A      1 
   A    D     N      1
```

Ideally I'd like to have the following:

```
  X1    X2     X3    count
  A     B      C      3
  A     D      N      4
```

I've tried adapting the code but I cannot make it work and haven't found a workaround neither with dplyr nor data.table.

```
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(DF)
DT.OUT <- DT[, list(size=sum(count)), 
    by=list(id1 = pmin(X1,X2,X3),id2 = c(X1,X2,X3)[!c(c(X1,X2,X3) %in% c(pmax(X1,X2,X3), pmin(X1,X2,X3)))] ,id3 = pmax(X1,X2,X3))]
```

Comment: May I ask how big is your dataset?

Comment: 10,865 rows and the same columns as shown (X1,X2,X3,count)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `apply` to sort the first three columns rowwise and then use `aggregate` to obtain the sum of `count`

```
aggregate(d$count, as.data.frame(t(apply(d[1:3], 1, sort))), sum)
#  V1 V2 V3 x
#1  A  B  C 3
#2  A  D  N 4
```

OR

```
d %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(grp = toString(sort(c(X1, X2, X3)))) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    group_by(grp) %>%
    summarize(count = sum(count)) %>%
    separate(grp, into = c("x1", "x2", "x3"))
## A tibble: 2 x 4
#  x1    x2    x3    count
#  <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
#1 A     B     C         3
#2 A     D     N         4
```

OR

```
f = as.character(sort(unique(unlist(d[1:3]))))
d %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(grp = toString(f[f %in% c(X1, X2, X3)])) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    group_by(grp) %>%
    summarize(count = sum(count)) %>%
    separate(grp, into = c("x1", "x2", "x3"))
## A tibble: 2 x 4
#  x1    x2    x3    count
#  <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
#1 A     B     C         3
#2 A     D     N         4
```

Comment: Excellent, very elegant solutions! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

Here is another option:

```
DT[, (cols) := {
        m <- as.matrix(.SD)
        as.data.table(matrix(m[order(row(m), m)], nrow=.N, byrow=TRUE))
    }, .SDcols=cols][, 
        sum(count), cols]
```

sample data and timing code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)

set.seed(0L)
nr <- 10865L
nc <- 3L
cols <- paste0("V", 1L:nc)
DT <- as.data.table(matrix(sample(LETTERS, nr*length(cols), TRUE), nrow=nr))[, count := 1L]
    
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(times=1L,
    a0 = aggregate(DT$count, as.data.frame(t(apply(DT[,1:3], 1, sort))), sum),
    a1 = {
        DT %>%
            rowwise() %>%
            mutate(grp = toString(sort(c(V1, V2, V3)))) %>%
            ungroup() %>%
            group_by(grp) %>%
            summarize(count = sum(count)) %>%
            separate(grp, into = c("V1", "V2", "V3"))
    },
    a2 = {
        unique(melt(DT[, rn := .I], id.var = c('rn', 'count'))[, 
            grp :=  toString(sort(unique(value))), rn], by = c("rn", "grp"))[, 
                .(count = sum(count)), grp]
    },
    a3 = {
        DT[, c(sort(.SD), list(count = count)), 1:nrow(DT), 
            .SDcols = V1:V3][, .(count = sum(count)), .(V1, V2, V3)]
    },
    a4 = DT[, (cols) := {
        m <- as.matrix(.SD)
        as.data.table(matrix(m[order(row(m), m)], nrow=.N, byrow=TRUE))
        }, .SDcols=cols][, 
            sum(count), cols]
)
```

timings:

```
Unit: milliseconds
 expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
   a0  295.3281  295.3281  295.3281  295.3281  295.3281  295.3281     1
   a1  281.8369  281.8369  281.8369  281.8369  281.8369  281.8369     1
   a2  284.0112  284.0112  284.0112  284.0112  284.0112  284.0112     1
   a3 4131.7221 4131.7221 4131.7221 4131.7221 4131.7221 4131.7221     1
   a4   11.7304   11.7304   11.7304   11.7304   11.7304   11.7304     1
```

Comment: Nice approach with the use of `matrix` conversion.  Would that have any impact on memory in big datasets?

Comment: @akrun Interesting question. I also think that there is an impact because of the conversion to matrix

Answer (score 3):

An option is to `melt` with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
unique(melt(DT[, rn := .I], id.var = c('rn', 'count'))[, 
  grp :=  toString(sort(unique(value))), rn], by = c("rn", "grp"))[, 
    .(count = sum(count)), grp]
#       grp count
#1: A, B, C     3
#2: A, D, N     4
```

---

Or another option is to loop over the rows to do the `sort` and then do a group by `sum`

```
DT[, c(sort(.SD), list(count = count)), 1:nrow(DT), 
     .SDcols = X1:X3][, .(count = sum(count)), .(X1, X2, X3)]
#   X1 X2 X3 count
#1:  A  B  C     3
#2:  A  D  N     4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df[, letters := pmap_chr(list(X1, X2, X3), ~c(...) %>% sort() %>% str_c(collapse = ""))]
df[, .N, by = letters]
```

gives:

```
   letters N
1:     ABC 3
2:     ADN 4
```

If you want X1, X2 and X3 columns then u can use one of:

```
extract(l, letters, into = c("X1", "X2", "X3"), "(.)(.)(.)")
separate(l, letters, into = c("X1", "X2", "X3"), sep = 1:3)
```

where `l` is data.frame containing variable letters and N. Then result is:

```
   X1 X2 X3 N
1:  A  B  C 3
2:  A  D  N 4
```

It's easy to adapt this algorithm to more than 3 columns.